# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions, error does not occur when called in setUserVisibleHint

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

The application is using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and an accompanied ViewPager. I have 3 fragments. I was attempting to call the `ViewPager` which is defined in the FragmentActivity class (SignUpActivity), in the 3rd fragment's `onCreateView()` and set the ViewPagers current item to the first page via the following line :

```
SignUpActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(0));
```

The above line resulted in the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

However through experimentation, when I ran the same `setCurrentItem(0)` line as above, in the `setUserVisibleHint()` method, the `ViewPager` displayed the 0th fragment as intended. Why did the ViewPager fail in the first case, I am assuming that the `ViewPager` cannot be invoked until it has finished any previous calls?

How would I be able to create a mechanism to call the `ViewPager` from the `FragmentActivity` and `setCurrentItem(x)` to any View I desired?

SignUpActivity code (FragmentActivity):

```
public class SignUpActivity extends FragmentActivity {
CustFSPA adapter;
static ViewPager pager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up); /

    adapter = new CustFSPA(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.signUpPager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public static class CustFSPA extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    int numberFragments = 3;
    static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public CustFSPA(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
        fragmentManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return numberFragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                // will display SignUpFragmentFirst
                return SignUpFragmentFirst.calledFromPager();
            case 1:
                return SignUpFragmentSecond.calledFromPager();
            default:
                return SignUpFragmentThird.calledFromPager();
        }
    }    
}
```

Third Fragment code: (No relevance of me providing the first two fragments' code)

```
public class SignUpFragmentThird extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onCreate third");

}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("Starting 3rd");
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("Paused 3rd");
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("Resumed 3rd");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    System.out.println("onCreateView third");
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.signUpPager);

    SignUpActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(0); <======= THIS WAS THE FIRST ATTEMPT WHICH FAILED AND RESULTED IN THE ERROR

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_up_fragment_third, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        System.out.println("THIRD is visible to the user");
        SignUpActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(1); <========= SECOND ATTEMPT WHICH WOKRED SUCCESSFULLY
    } else {
        System.out.println("THIRD is not visible to the user");
    }
}

static SignUpFragmentThird calledFromPager(){
    System.out.println("third case def  " + SignUpActivity.pager.getCurrentItem());
    System.out.println("calledFromPager third");
    SignUpFragmentThird fragment = new SignUpFragmentThird();
    return fragment;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: why are you calling this SignUpActivity.pager.setCurrentItem(0); in third fragment?

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir Certain points in my app, a user will be navigated back to a former View if they have not satisfied certain conditions. I am just trying to understand why the setCurrentItem() didnt work in the former attempt

Comment: you can create a callback or setTargetFragment in order to do operation in parentClass. And setUserVisibleHint calls before onCreateView. And onCreateView also calls before onActivity Create.May be your activity is not yet created. So try calling that method in onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

You can set viewPager to any desired view by this call.Basically this listener tracks the pages of viewpager. you need to implement it in Parent Activity.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.i("TAG", "position: " + position);
       //Here you can change the position of the viewPager.
       //you have three fragnment so when the position would be positon=2 then you can set viewPager to any view
       switch(position)
         case 2:
          pager.setCurrentItem(0));
         break;
    }
});
```

Hope it will help.